# Category theory inquiry: limits

Tags: category-theory

excuse me but what is the best way to prove that the functor $F: \mathcal{C}^{2} \to \mathcal{C} \times \mathcal{C}$ creates limits, where $F(f:A \to B) = (A,B)$? Not a homework question - just trying to understand Maclane.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Do you have troubles in applying the definition? Is there something you don't understand?